were made in the middle of twenty - [not 'the twenty twenty' or 'the twentieth']

...apparently some of these allegations re by whistleblowers were made in the middle of twenty.

Youtube, 'Sen. Hawley Makes Biden Nominee Tremble Asking Him About Hunter Biden Laptop & FBI's Secret Memo', 08:13
Is it specifically AmE? What style is this?
Why not say  'the twenty twenty' or 'the twentieth'?

Provide the link so we can confirm that you have not misheard.  It could mean the year 2020.  The "middle of twenty" would mean late spring, early summer of 2020.  It is simply a way of speaking curtly for the sake of brevity when going over many detailed chronological facts.

@TimR https://youtu.be/f-T00JjoJYg?t=493

Thanks. Yes, "in the middle of '20".  The year 2020.  To refer to the year as "20" is common when a chronology of events is the context, and everyone understands what is meant in that context.  But if you called customer service after receiving an overdue notice on an invoice,  and said "I paid this bill in 23!", it might not be understood.

Compare the summer of sixty-nine. Why not the summer of nineteen sixty-nine?

Oh, come on! Well, how about back in sixty-nine then? Both back in and OP's cited in the middle of obviously refer to time-frames (and either could just as easily refer to a past month, rather than a year).

In OP's defense, Senator Graham speaks the time phrase in a rather lifeless manner, with little of the sort of expression that accompanies "back in '69" ,  and nineteen-sixty-nine with its long vowels + nasals is much more of a mouthul than twenty-twenty, taking much longer to say.  There's very little reason to shorten 2020 to 20. Furthermore, late in the century is much riper for such shortening than early in a century.

And, "the middle of" is less clearly temporal than "back in".  Even I found the senator's shortening of 2020 to 20 a little odd, and I listen to that worm every day.

By that early/late in the century remark, I  mean when the shortening utterance is spoken, not the year being referenced.

I just tried both video links and YouTube is claiming it's been taken down by the uploader. However, judging by context, this is lousy but comprehensible American English. What the speaker should have said was, "...some of these allegations re by whistleblowers were made in the middle of twenty-twenty" meaning sometime between May and August (or, arguably, April-September),  2020. Honestly, in the middle of a confirmation hearing, the speaker should have been much less ambiguous.
